# Erro ao configurar Passport no Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, oauth

Tenho uma API em laravel e nela, precisa preciso autenticar as requisições de acesso. Então, utilizei o Passport Laravel, só que de acordo o retorno da API, existe alguma definição que não informei no meu código.

Na minha rota, informo o tipo do middleware:

```
Route::get('/members', 'PessoaController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Em config/app.php informei as *class*

```
 Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
    Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
```

Mas quando faço qualquer requisição na minha API, tenho o seguinte retorno:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>    Type error: Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware            \CreateFreshApiToken::__construct() must be an instance of Laravel\Passport\ApiTokenCookieFactory, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in /home/secbase.com.br/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 208

Comment: Você pode adicionar a classe middleware da past http em sua pergunta?

Answer (score -1):

Você injetou a trait `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` na sua classe `User`?

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
}
```

Registrou as rotas do passport no `AuthServiceProvider` ?

```
public function boot()
{
  $this->registerPolicies();

  Passport::routes();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

Comment: Sim, apliquei essas definições.

Answer (score -1):

Não está faltando o construct?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

Comment: Tem o construtor, só esqueci de expor aqui no código.